# Is it possible to tell if a date palm is male or female by looking at its roots?

Tags: palm

There are some gardeners in my locality who claim to know gardeners that can tell if a date palm is fruit-bearing (female) or not (male) while it is still a sapling by just looking at its roots.

Is there any credibility to this claim? As it takes several years for a date palm to bear fruit, it would be quite useful to be able to know this in advance.

Comment: Well, its just a claim - without actual proof or evidence, that's all it is. Certainly from a scientific point of view, no, there's no way to know until the plant matures, unless you carry out the new genetic testing to get the DNA profile. Ask whoever says they can do this to show you exactly how...